# Django + Python social auth: How to configure OAuth for GitHub Enterprise?

Tags: django, github, oauth-2.0

With Django and social-auth-app-django, I can authorize with `https://github.com` with `social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2` backend.

And I'm trying to switch it to our GitHub Enterprise based on this documentation;
https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/github_enterprise.html#github-enterprise

Here is my `settings.py`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'social_django',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
...
    'social_django.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
...
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'social_django.context_processors.backends',
                'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
...
]

SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_URL = 'https://github.mycompany.com/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_API_URL = 'https://github.mycompany.com/api/v3/'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_KEY = '----'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GITHUB_ENTERPRISE_SECRET = '----'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_core.backends.github_enterprise.GithubEnterpriseOAuth2',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

But it complains with below error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/social-auth/login/github/
Raised by:  social_django.views.auth

Backend not found
```

I'm sure the class `social_core.backends.github_enterprise.GithubEnterpriseOAuth2` is in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/social_core/backends/github_enterprise.py`.

If I use the backend as `social_core.backends.github.GithubOAuth2` it redirects to `https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?` which is not desired.

Could you please guide me how to setup backend for GitHub Enterprise?

Comment: Oh, I missed to change "{% url 'social:begin' 'github' %}" to github-enterprise. Let me check!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"{% url 'social:begin' 'github' %}"` should be `"{% url 'social:begin' 'github-enterprise' %}"`.